# How to create new App for an existing app?

Tags: ios, bundle-identifier

In Android or Java, we have the package name determine the app. I can create a new project with the same package name in a different system and then upload it to Play Store.

Question: What is the equivalent for the package in iOS? Is it the bundle id?

Apple just introduced SwiftUI. In case I planned to change my apps to SWiftUI, can I do the following and will it update my existing app in AppStore

1. Current project bundle id - com.company.app1
2. Create a new project in Xcode and set the bundle id as com.company.app1
3. Make all necessary changes
4. When I archive and upload, will it update my current existing project in AppStore?

I believe it will update, but I may be completely wrong.

Comment: The bundle id is the only things that matters.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation